# Modeling heterogenous graphs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph-theory, dsl, typechecking

How can I model what I will call "heterogenous graphs" in haskell, such that the type-correctness of the graph can be verified at compile time?

For this purpose, a heterogenous graph is a set of nodes, each with a certain type label, and a set of edges, each with a source type label and a destination type label.

We wish to *statically* ensure that, when an edge is added to a graph, the source type label of that edge matches the type label of the source node, and the destination type label of that edge matches the type label of the destination node. But we don't wish to do that in the trivial way (by forcing the entire graph to contain only nodes with one particular type label).

Comment: By "type", do you mean compile-time type? If so, they're going to need some sort of run-time residue. Maybe a GADT if the set of types is easy to enumerate, maybe using `Typeable` if the set of types is not easy to enumerate.

Comment: Would you be interested in a safe interface that uses unsafe features internally? What operations should your graph support? And are there any restrictions on the type of the nodes?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Yes, using unsafe features internally would be fine. Typeable or erasing phantom node/edge types would be preferred to something like unsafeCoerce, but if its neccessary and externally safe anything goes. Now that you ask, it might be sufficient operations to, once the graph is known to be correctly typed, convert it to a homogenous representation. Maybe a TH splice that checks a homogenous representation for correctness in this sense might fulfill all my needs, I will explore that path a bit.

Comment: I think one could have an implementation that stores nodes of type `Any`, exposes an interface using tagged types, uses `unsafeCoerce` internally, and maybe a higher rank type (like `runST`) to make sure nodes of different graphs are not confused.

But it would be helpful to see the your “dream interface” first.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure how I would go about enforcing this at compile time—I think it requires that your graphs be completely static?—but it’s relatively straightforward to enforce at runtime using `Typeable`. Here’s a sketch of what that would look like. First, I’ll start with typed `Node` and `Edge` types:

```
data Node a = Node a
data Edge a b = Edge !Int !Int
```

Wrap them in existentials:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Typeable

data SomeNode
  = forall a. (Typeable a)
  => SomeNode (Node a)

data SomeEdge
  = forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b)
  => SomeEdge (Edge a b)
```

Have a heterogeneous graph data type that uses the existentially quantified types:

```
import Data.IntMap (IntMap)

-- Not a great representation, but simple for illustration.
data Graph = Graph !(IntMap SomeNode) [SomeEdge]
```

And then operations that perform dynamic type checks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import qualified Data.IntMap as IntMap

addNode
  :: forall a. (Typeable a)
  => Int -> a -> Graph -> Maybe Graph
addNode i x (Graph ns es) = case IntMap.lookup i ns of

  -- If a node already exists at a given index:
  Just (SomeNode (existing :: Node e)) -> case eqT @e @a of

    -- Type-preserving replacement is allowed, but…
    Just Refl -> Just $ Graph ns' es

    -- …*type-changing* replacement is *not* allowed,
    -- since it could invalidate existing edges.
    Nothing -> Nothing

  -- Insertion is of course allowed.
  Nothing -> Just $ Graph ns' es

  where
    ns' = IntMap.insert i (SomeNode (Node x)) ns

-- To add an edge:
addEdge
  :: forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b)
  => Edge a b -> Graph -> Maybe Graph
addEdge e@(Edge f t) (Graph ns es) = do

  -- The ‘from’ node must exist…
  SomeNode (fn :: Node tfn) <- IntMap.lookup f ns
  -- …and have the correct type; and
  Refl <- eqT @a @tfn

  -- The ‘to’ node must exist…
  SomeNode (tn :: Node ttn) <- IntMap.lookup t ns
  -- …and have the correct type.
  Refl <- eqT @b @ttn

  pure $ Graph ns $ SomeEdge e : es
```

Now this succeeds:

```
pure (Graph mempty mempty)
  >>= addNode 0 (1 :: Int)
  >>= addNode 1 ('x' :: Char)
  >>= addEdge (Edge 0 1 :: Edge Int Char)
```

But changing `Int`/`Char` in `Edge Int Char` to invalid types, or `0`/`1` to invalid indices, will fail and return `Nothing`.

Comment: This is a good dynamic solution. Accepting the condition that the graphs are static (say, in an EDSL for describing mechatronic systems or bond graphs), do you see any route to a statically checked solution?

Comment: @DougMcClean: Could you explain a bit more about your use case & what operations you need? I’m playing with a solution like `data Graph (ns :: [(Nat, *)]) (es :: [(Nat, Nat)]) = Graph (Nodes ns) (Edges es)` where the whole graph structure is encoded in the type and `Nodes` & `Edges` are type families that give you fields for runtime values. API could be `emptyGraph & addNode @0 (1 :: Int) & addNode @1 ('x' :: Char) & addEdge @0 @1 (Edge 0.5 :: Edge Int Char) :: Graph '[(1, Char), (0, Int)] '[(0, 1)]` using `TypeApplications` to specify the labels—which could also use `Symbol` instead of `Nat`.

Comment: My use case is modeling automation systems. A `Node Device` would represent the internal logic/behavior of a physical device like a motor or sensor, and would be connected by an `Edge Device ElectricalPort` to an electrical port. Static checking would ensure that `wire :: Edge ElectricalPort ElectricalPort` couldn't be used where `tubing :: Edge PneumaticPort PneumaticPort` was intended. The type labels are phantoms and can be erased once checked, or converted to some simple term level representation, so the query interface can check the labels and return inside a `Maybe`.

Comment: Ideally there would be some way to add a whole subgraph as if it were an edge, like `pressureSensor :: ActsLikeAnEdge PneumaticPort ElectricalPort` where in fact that pressure sensor is modelled with some internal details.

Comment: @DougMcClean: Hm, I wonder if you might want `Arrow`s? E.g., with `type Edge i o = Kleisli IO i o; type Source o = Edge () o; type Sink i = Edge i ()` you could write things like `proc (power, pneumatic) -> do { power <- powerCable <<< battery -< (); sensor <- dataCable <<< pressureSensor -< pneumatic; result <- dataCable <<< device -< (power, sensor); display -< result }` with suitable definitions of things like `battery :: Source PowerOut`, `powerCable :: Edge PowerOut PowerIn`, `device :: Edge (PowerIn, DataIn Double) (DataOut Double)`, `display :: Sink (DataOut Double)`…

Comment: Well, that should be just `proc (pneumatic)` actually, since the `battery` presumably generates power, hah. Just an illustration of how you can get a static graph structure by composing things that act more or less like regular functions equipped with whatever extra structure you want. Arrows let you do analysis of the graph as well, described here: https://elvishjerricco.github.io/2017/03/10/profunctors-arrows-and-static-analysis.html

Comment: Thanks @jon-purdy, that elvishjerricco link is very interesting. I don't follow all of it, but I will reread it a few times until I do.